# Script for identifying landmarks and cropping mouth from images using OpenCV doesn't see faces

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, dlib

So what I'm trying to do using OpenCV, dlib, and Python is to basically identify facial landmarks on a set of images using dlib and then crop the the mouths from those very same images and save them as separate images with ".jpg" extensions.

This here is the code:

```
import numpy as np  
import cv2  
import dlib
import sys
import skimage 
from PIL import Image
import os
import glob

#Everything is imported here

folderpath = sys.argv[1]
cascPath = sys.argv[2]
PREDICTOR_PATH = "/home/victor/facial-landmarks/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat" 

#user supplies the folderpath and cascpath in a terminal/command prompt
#predictor_path is already set

imageformat = ".tif"
path = folderpath
imfilelist = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(imageformat)]

#only images with ".tif" extensions in the folder interest us, we create a
#list with paths to those images    

data = np.array([])
for IMG in imfilelist:
    image = cv2.imread(IMG) #this for-loop iterates through images we need
    np.append(data, image) # reads them, and appends them to the data 
                           # numpy array

gray = np.array([])
for j in range(0, len(data)):
    cvtimg = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(data[j]), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    np.append(gray, cvtimg) #empty numpy array called gray is declared
                            # for-loop goes through all RGB pictures
                            # stored in data, converts them to grayscale
                            # and stores them in gray



MOUTH_OUTLINE_POINTS = list(range(48, 61))  
MOUTH_INNER_POINTS = list(range(61, 68))

#defines the landmarks for the Mouth Outline and the inner mouth points  

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

#faceCascade is defined here, cascPath which is user supplied is the param  

predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(PREDICTOR_PATH)  

faces = np.array([])   
for i in gray:
    face = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray[i], scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(100,100))
    np.append(faces, face) #this for-loop tries to detect faces and append       
                           #them to the empty numpy array called faces

print("Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces)))

# nothing is displayed beyond this print statement               

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:  

  dlib_rect = dlib.rectangle(int(x), int(y), int(x + w), int(y + h))  

  landmarks = np.matrix([[p.x, p.y]  
              for p in predictor(IMAGES, dlib_rect).parts()])  

  landmarks_display = landmarks[MOUTH_OUTLINE_POINTS + MOUTH_INNER_POINTS]

  highX = 0
  lowX = 1000
  highY = 0
  lowY = 1000

  for idx, point in enumerate(landmarks_display):  
    pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])  
    cv2.circle(image, pos, 2, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=-1)
  if (pos[0] > highX):
   highX = pos[0]
  if (pos[0] < lowX):
   lowX = pos[0]
  if (pos[1] > highY):
   highY = pos[1]
  if (pos[1] < lowY):
   lowY = pos[1]
  print (lowX, lowY, highX, highY)


  CONSTANT_FACTOR = 0.325
  delta_x = highX-lowX
  delta_y = highY - lowY
  low_x_adj = lowX - int(delta_x * CONSTANT_FACTOR)
  high_x_adj = highX + int(delta_x * CONSTANT_FACTOR)
  low_y_adj = lowY - int(delta_y * 0.2)
  high_y_adj = highY + int(delta_y * CONSTANT_FACTOR)

  crop_img = image[low_y_adj:high_y_adj,low_x_adj:high_x_adj]
  cv2.imwrite("Cropped_Mouth.jpg", crop_img)
  cv2.imshow("Cropped_Mouth.jpg", crop_img)

  cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Now, I've checked the paths and they are correct. I don't get any syntax errors, runtime errors, nothing. The script runs, but no output is produced other than the following print statement: `print("Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces)))`.

I assume it runs what comes after it, but there is no output on the screen and nothing is saved in my home folder (which is were the output pictures of cropped mouths are normally stored). The original script which was meant to work with one image only works perfectly, but this one doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any ideas and suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

P.S if the problem is with the code after the line that gets printed, I still didn't start working on that part for this script because I believe it is the code above the print statement that is faulty in some way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use dlib face detector for detecting faces?. Below is the code to detect faces using dlib face detector and save mouth from faces with a .jpg extension. I just modified the dlib face landmarks.py given in the python examples folder of dlib.

```
import sys
import os
import dlib
import glob
import cv2

predictor_path = "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
faces_folder_path = "path/to/faces/folder"

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
win = dlib.image_window()
i = 0
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.tiff")):
    print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
    img = cv2.imread(f)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

    # to clear the previous overlay. Useful when multiple faces in the same photo
    win.clear_overlay()

    # to show the image
    win.set_image(img)

    # Ask the detector to find the bounding boxes of each face. The 1 in the
    # second argument indicates that we should upsample the image 1 time. This
    # will make everything bigger and allow us to detect more faces.
    dets = detector(img, 1)
    print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(dets)))
    for k, d in enumerate(dets):
        print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {}".format(
            k, d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))
        # Get the landmarks/parts for the face in box d.
        shape = predictor(img, d)
        i += 1
        # The next lines of code just get the coordinates for the mouth
        # and crop the mouth from the image.This part can probably be optimised
        # by taking only the outer most points.
        xmouthpoints = [shape.part(x).x for x in range(48,67)]
        ymouthpoints = [shape.part(x).y for x in range(48,67)]
        maxx = max(xmouthpoints)
        minx = min(xmouthpoints)
        maxy = max(ymouthpoints)
        miny = min(ymouthpoints) 

        # to show the mouth properly pad both sides
        pad = 10
        # basename gets the name of the file with it's extension
        # splitext splits the extension and the filename
        # This does not consider the condition when there are multiple faces in each image.
        # if there are then it just overwrites each image and show only the last image.
        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]

        crop_image = img[miny-pad:maxy+pad,minx-pad:maxx+pad]
        cv2.imshow('mouth',crop_image)
        # The mouth images are saved in the format 'mouth1.jpg, mouth2.jpg,..
        # Change the folder if you want to. They are stored in the current directory
        cv2.imwrite(filename+'.jpg',crop_image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        win.add_overlay(shape)

    win.add_overlay(dets)
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. Only question is, how do I go about keeping the names of the tiff files used? So if it is called abc123.tif, I want the output to be abc123.jpg.

Comment: I edited the code for that. Keep in mind that if there are multiple faces in one image then it saves only one mouth. If you want all mouth images, then you need to change the file name every time.

Comment: I've noticed the edit, thanks. This does precisely what is needed. I'm dealing with images that have only 1 face.